# FilePicker Plugin is not working in IOS Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am working on Xamarin Cross Platform Application, i want to pick document from device storage, For this i am using Xam.Plugin.FilePicker and its working in android when i call from pcl project but its not working in IOS Project, its showing an error as `only one operation can be active at a time at plugin.filepicker.filepickerimplementation.takemediaasync` and these are the 2 lines which i am using

```
  var filePicker = Plugin.FilePicker.CrossFilePicker.Current;
                     await filePicker.PickFile();
```

and in info.plist i also added permissions as `<key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
    <true />`

If not, Is their any other way to do this only for IOS Platfrom from PCL?

Comment: Which package did you use?

Comment: `Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker`

Comment: first i used this one `Xam.Plugin.FilePicker` and then i used `Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker` both giving me same error

Comment: Did you checkout the beta package for `Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker`?

Comment: yes i am using `2.0.64-beta`

Comment: you can use this plugin on alternative case [link](https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows)